# Using XMLWriter to create a custom header in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

I'm fairly new to XML and very new to using the XMLWriter object. I've been successful in using it to write a "Well Formed" XML file, but after many failed attempts to create the needed header, below, I've decided to come here for some insight.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE IDMS-XML SYSTEM "http://eclipseinc.com/dtd/IDMS-XML.dtd"> 
<IDMS-XML>
....
```

Here's the beginning of my code (very standard):

```
using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("SendXML.xml"))
{
    xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
    ....
```

I've tried using things like xmlWriter.WriteString() to force it in, but that has been unsuccessful for me. Thanks for any and all insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to write to the xml file you need to create the `XmlTextWriter` then create a node to make a header. Hope this helps you out a bit.

```
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("filename",System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);                  writer.WriteStartDocument(True)

    writer.WriteStartElement("Start Element Name")
    createNode("NodeName", writer)
    writer.WriteEndElement()
    writer.WriteEndDocument()
    writer.Close()


public void createnode(String nodename, XmlTextWriter writer)
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("Name Here")
    writer.WriteString(nodename)
    writer.WriteEndElement()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more clear what the “it” you are trying to “force in” is. Do you mean the `<!DOCTYPE ...`? That is a doctype declaration, and `XmlWriter` has a built-in method for adding one. To create a `SYSTEM` doctype try:

```
xmlWriter.WriteDocType("IDMS-XML", null, "http://eclipseinc.com/dtd/IDMS-XML.dtd", null);
```

If that is not what you mean you must be more explicit.